# Wordpress Blog Error Showing all Files

Tags: php, wordpress

I have website [www.soulspectrum.org](http://www.soulspectrum.org)

I don't know what happens to it. as it was working  fine yesterday. Anybody have idea about this. i guess some files missing it showing all files to me.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like your web server (Apache) is incorrectly configured. Either `mod_php5` or `mod_dir` are missing, or [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html) doesn't include `index.php`.

Comment: There also may've something happend with .htaccess file in the root directory of your project.

Comment: You defiantly need to handle this soon because your config file is readable: http://www.soulspectrum.org/wp-config.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not setup to run.  This is all done in the apache config file. If you are using Ubuntu (or a Debian based OS, I provide easier directions at the bottom).

You need to enable mod_php

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

You need to add the handler into Apache for php5:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

And then setup index.php in the index module:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

For Ubuntu or Debian based:

```
sudo apt-get install php5

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

If it is neither of these, let me know, I can probably help with whatever combination of setups you might have.